# How can I build a shuffleboard surface that is movable?

Tags: tools, appliances

My friends and I are planning on building a shuffleboard this weekend. However shuffleboards are pretty long (~16 feet) and moving the full board is going to be a pain.

How can we build it so that we could move it later? One problem is that the shuffleboard surface is supposed to be lacquered and very smooth, and we want to be careful to provide a good playing surface.

I would appreciate some ideas about how to build it.

Comment: This is a table top version?

Comment: Yes, like the kind you play in a bar.

Comment: Put wheels on it, and make it as light as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this link:

http://www.model-railroad-infoguy.com/modular.html

They build modular model railroad tables - and I'm thinking that's kind of what you're looking for.

I would want a design made up of two or three separate table bases, each of which can be independently leveled at each leg.  When perfectly level, your top surface, something like a high gloss butcherblock top I guss - should line up perfectly evenly.

You'll want some kind of tension latches connecting each section to its neighbors as well, to pull the surface together good and tight once its assembled, to eliminate the seam.

For building techniques, I'd build the bases and top surface separately at first.  The bases can be separate, but the top should be built in one solid piece.  I wouldn't do the gloss coat yet though - I'd build the top and then cut it into two/three interlocking segments and mount them on their respective bases, ensuring they can close up tight to give a nearly perfect surface.  Then and only then would I separate the sections and do the finish treatments on each.

Comment: I had similar thoughts, but would have split the sections first, assembled them together with the latches (some kind of T&G design would be ideal), and then sand the entire surface, so that it's perfect across the latched joints.

Comment: I thought about that approach - but I was thinking that building the surface as one piece would make it easier to create that perfectly level surface.